# Checking if jasmine test is called with a done callback

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'd like to replace some functions inside of test environment to make sure that they're only called inside test with `done` callback available. This is to catch (for example) cases where `setTimeout` is used in a test which does not wait for completion. I'm trying to achieve something like `UnhandledPromiseRejection` here, but for timers.

But the part I can't figure out is: How would I check if the test I'm currently running is using the `done` callback or not? (in a function down the stack, not in the test itself)